# Split environment alters spacing around binary operators

Tags: math-mode, spacing, amsmath, math-operators

I've been using `split` environment from `amsmath`.  A problem that I've run into is that if an `&` for alignment is placed next to a binary operator, the spacing on that side of the operator is reduced from what it should be.

Here is a minimal example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
    f(x) = m x^2 + b
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
    f(x) = & m x^2 \\
    & + b
\end{split}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image: split spacing]

Any idea how to avoid this issue without having to fiddle around with manual spaces each time?

Comment: Either use `&=` or `={}&`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The usual way of using the alignment operator is either `& =` (on the left side), or via `={} &` (to correct the spacing around the binary relation. Here's how you would use both:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}% http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath
\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
  f(x) = m x^2 + b
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
  \begin{split}
    f(x) = & m x^2 \\
    & + b
  \end{split}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
  \begin{split}
    f(x) & = m x^2 \\
    &\phantom{{}={}} + b
  \end{split}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
  \begin{split}
    f(x) ={} & m x^2 \\
    & + b
  \end{split}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Note how the correction for the `\phantom` relation `=` ensures proper spacing.

Comment: #3 is the only one i'd consider "correct".  another variant (essentially what's recommended by knuth, migrated from plain tex to latex): `f(x) &= mx^2 \\ &\quad b`.  (and you left a "how" out of the last sentence.  not editing, since i just put in my own answer, and it looks greedy to have my fingerprints on all the answers.)

Comment: Thanks.  The last method (#4) works perfectly and is reasonably convenient.  Do you know why the ampersand messes up spacing even though it is only being used as formatting mark-up?  A technical limitation of `LaTeX`?

Comment: @tarheels: As mentioned in [barabara beeton's answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/124619/5764), it is *expected* to have the relation on the right side of `&`. So, technically you're not conforming to the required syntax. If you do, there's no problem. If you don't you have to do some magic to correct for this.

Comment: @tarheels -- latex interprets input linearly.  if the `&` comes after the `=`, it's too late to decide what spacing to use.

Comment: Ok, I can see now that it's syntactically required.  However, it does look very much like an unintended side effect rather than a feature.  I was just wonder if there were any good reasons for the split environment to alter spaces in this manner.

Comment: @tarheels: As @barbara mentioned, it's a case of syntax. In a similar vein there are other things that are physically required in LaTeX in some instances, yet in other's it's defined a little more loosely. For example, while you can end most environments using `\end {<somenv>}` (note the space), this is not possible with `verbatim` (by default). You explicitly need `\end{verbatim}`. There may be other instances where things just have to work a specific way, or else it fails. In some instances you can correct for this if the failure isn't fatal.

Comment: Is there a difference between using `\hphantom` and using `\phantom` (in #3)?

Comment: By the way, in my opinion none of the options solves the problem, because the plus sign is also a relation symbol, and therefore it is also a spacing issue there.

Comment: @MatemáticosChibchas: One could remove the space to the left of the `+` so that it aligns with the upper portion of the equation.

Answer (score 4):

you're not following the recommended/required syntax.  from the manual (`texdoc amsldoc`):

> In the structures that do alignment (`split`, `align` and
>   variants), relation symbols have an `&` before them but not
>   after -- unlike `eqnarray`. Putting the `&` after the
>   relation symbol will interfere with the normal spacing; it has to go
>   before.

Comment: Ah, thanks.  I looked in the `amsmdoc` "User's Guide", but it didn't specifically mention this rule.

Comment: @tarheels -- p.3, the paragraph just before "3.2 single equations".