# Spacing around binary operators in alignments

Tags: spacing, alignment

Consider this example:

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
(\,&p\in P\to p\neq 0\\
&\wedge\ \pi=3\,)
\end{align*}
%
\begin{align*}
(\,&p\in P\to p\neq 0\\
&{\wedge}\ \pi=3\,)
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image: example]

As discussed in [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/124615/32352) question, there are spacing issues when using & and binary operators. In the first alignment, even though I am putting the & before the binary operator (wedge) there is an extra spacing. Of course, the attempted solution (second alignment) also messes with the spacing, because the curly brackets neutralize the binary operator spacing. This perhaps can be solved by making binary operator spacing sideways, but I don't know if this is even possible.

**EDIT**

As requested by @azetina: I want the wedge symbol to be aligned with respect to the letter "p" as in the second alignment, but with the correct spacing after (, namely, as in the first alignment).

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve? Your question is not clear or defines what you want to align or depicts the end result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TeX adds `\medmuskip` space *around* a binary operation symbol when it's surrounded by suitable atoms.

In your case the left atom is `{}` supplied by the `&` and `\pi` is the right atom.

Remove the spacing:

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
(\,&p\in P\to p\neq 0\\
&\mspace{-\medmuskip}\wedge\pi=3\,)
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Also `\negmedspace`.